# the resizable panel with table and resizable columns

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like this table to follow the resizable panel, but also make the columns resizable.
Currently the table exceeds if I resize the panel.
http://jsfiddle.net/ericire/u1Lcd26n/35/
clic on the button
PS
it's funny I put a link jsfiddle and I'm told that we must put code. So I put code and I'm told that there is too much code hahaha
so here are the details requested

Edit : I finally succeeded
here is the right code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" tabindex="0">
        <div id="menu1">
            <table class="tab" id="table1">
                <tr>
                    <td><button class="tablinks" id="Par" onclick="menu(event, 'Par')" title="Permet de sélectionner des parcelles du calque parcelles vecteur pour les ajouter au calque Annotations">Par+</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div><!-- panneau utilitaire parcellaire -->
        <div class="tabContent" id="ParContent">
            <div class="titrePanneau" id="titrePanneauParc">
                Utilitaire parcellaire
            </div>
            <div class="" id="attributs_cadre">
                <div class="soustitrePanneau" id="attributs">
                    Attributs
                </div>
                <div class="tableauAttributs" id="ajoutAttrCav" title="ajouter les attributs caviar">
                    c
                </div>
                <div class="tableauAttributs" id="ajoutLigne" title="ajouter une ligne au tableau">
                    +
                </div>
                <div class="tableauAttributs" id="ajoutAttrEmp" title="ajouter les attributs du polygone sélectionné">
                    ◄
                </div>
                <div class="tableauAttributs" id="supprimLignes" title="supprimer le contenu du tableau">
                    x
                </div>
                <table id="tableauAttributs">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="ent">Nom</td>
                            <td class="ent">Valeur</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tbody">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="td"><input type="text"></td>
                            <td class="td"><input type="text"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="td"><input type="text"></td>
                            <td class="td"><input type="text"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="td"><input type="text"></td>
                            <td class="td"><input type="text"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="td"><input type="text"></td>
                            <td class="td"><input type="text"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="td"><input type="text"></td>
                            <td class="td"><input type="text"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="td"><input type="text"></td>
                            <td class="td"><input type="text"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="td"><input type="text"></td>
                            <td class="td"><input type="text"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="td"><input type="text"></td>
                            <td class="td"><input type="text"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="td"><input type="text"></td>
                            <td class="td"><input type="text"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
    /* Style the tab */

#menu1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 5px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.tab {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
}
/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(235, 107, 10, 1);
    color: #4d2e00;
    padding: 8px 1px 8px 1px;
    width: 34px;
    border: 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-family: Rubik;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: normal;
    color: white;
}
/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(196, 89, 8, 0.8);
    color: white;
}
/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */

.tab button.active {
    background-color: rgba(122, 56, 5, 0.8);
    color: white;
}
/* pour enlever le focus du bouton */

button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
}
#ParContent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 42px;
    height: 390px;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 1px #999;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.titrePanneau {
    height: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: #6a360d;
    padding-left: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}
.soustitrePanneau {
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: gray;
    text-align: center;
}
/* panneau utilitaire parcellaire #ParContent*/

#attributs_cadre {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    left: 2px;
    width: 310px;
    padding: 2px;
    height: 187px;
}
#type, #attributs {
    height: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: gray;
    text-align: center;
}
#ajoutAttrCav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    right: 52px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#ajoutLigne {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    right: 35px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#ajoutAttrEmp {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right: 15px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#supprimLignes {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    right: 4px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    font-family: arial;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#tableauAttributs {
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    top: 24px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
#tableauAttributs tr .ent {
    border: 1px solid white;
    text-align: center;
}
#tableauAttributs tbody {
    display: block;
    max-height: 134px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#tableauAttributs input {
    width: 100%
}
#tableauAttributs thead, tbody tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
#tableauAttributs tbody {
    display: block;
    padding: 1px;
}
#tableauAttributs tbody tr {
    width: calc(100% - 3px);
}
#tableauAttributs thead {
    background: #b3b3b3;
}
```

```js
    $(function() {
    $("#ParContent").resizable({
        handles: 'e',
        minWidth: 320,
        alsoResize: "#attributs_cadre"
    }).on("resize", function() {
        //le tableau
        var cadre = $("#attributs_cadre").width()
        document.querySelector('#tableauAttributs').style.width = cadre + 'px';
        //les entetes
        document.querySelector('#tableauAttributs thead').style.width = cadre - 19 + 'px';
    });
});

function menu(evt) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks, menu;
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabContent");
    menu = document.getElementById(evt.currentTarget.id + 'Content');
    var bouton = document.getElementById(evt.currentTarget.id);
    var pos = getPosition('Par');
    var larg = bouton.offsetWidth;
    // changer apparence bouton
    if (evt.currentTarget.className === "tablinks active") { //si bouton actif
        evt.currentTarget.className = "tablinks"; //desactive boutton
        menu.style.visibility = 'hidden'; //on masque le menu
    } else {
        //on remets le tableau initial
        const element = document.querySelector('#attributs_cadre')
        const Cadre_width = element.style.width
        if (Cadre_width != 310) {
            element.style.width = '310px';
            document.querySelector("#tableauAttributs").style.width = '310px';
            document.querySelector("#tableauAttributs thead").style.width = '291px';
        }
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {;
            tablinks[i].className = 'tablinks'; //on desactive tous les boutons
            tabcontent[i].style.visibility = 'hidden'; //on masque tous les menus
        };
        evt.currentTarget.className = "tablinks active"; //puis on active le bouton
        var style = style = window.getComputedStyle(menu);
        menu.style.visibility = 'visible'; //on affiche ce menu et actualise le css
        menu.style.position = style.getPropertyValue('position');
        menu.style.top = pos[1] + 'px';
        menu.style.left = (pos[0] + larg + 2) + 'px';
        menu.style.height = style.getPropertyValue('height');
        if (evt.currentTarget.id == 'Par') {
            menu.style.width = '320px'
        } else {
            menu.style.width = style.getPropertyValue('width');
        }
        menu.style.backgroundColor = style.getPropertyValue('backgroundColor');
        menu.style.color = style.getPropertyValue('color');
        menu.style.borderRadius = style.getPropertyValue('borderRadius');
        menu.style.boxShadow = style.getPropertyValue('boxShadow');
        menu.style.zIndex = style.getPropertyValue('zIndex');
    };
};
/**
 * gestion des boutons pour afficher le menu
 * @param evt: l'evenement du click
 *
 * @returns affiche le menu
 */
//pour activer les clics boutons menus
window.onload = function() {
    menu(evt);
    document.getElementById(this.id).onclick = menu;
}
document.getElementById("Par").onclick = menu;

function getPosition(Id) {
    console.trace('getPosition(Id)')
    var left = 0;
    var top = 0;
    //On récupère l'élément
    var e = document.getElementById(Id);
    console.log("e", e)
    //Tant que l'on a un élément parent
    while (e.offsetParent != undefined && e.offsetParent != null) {
        //On ajoute la position de l'élément parent
        left += e.offsetLeft + (e.clientLeft != null ? e.clientLeft : 0);
        top += e.offsetTop + (e.clientTop != null ? e.clientTop : 0);
        e = e.offsetParent;
    }
    return new Array(left, top);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your js code with the following.

```
$(function() {
  $("#ParContent").resizable({
    handles: 'e',
    minWidth: 290,
    alsoResize: "#attributs_cadre,#tableauAttributs,#tableauAttributs input,#tableauAttributs thead"
  });

});

function menu(evt) { 

  var i, tabcontent, tablinks, menu;
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabContent");
  menu = document.getElementById(evt.currentTarget.id + 'Content');
  var bouton = document.getElementById(evt.currentTarget.id);

  var pos = getPosition('Par'); 
  var larg = bouton.offsetWidth;
  // changer apparence bouton
  if (evt.currentTarget.className === "tablinks active") { //si bouton actif
    evt.currentTarget.className = "tablinks"; //desactive boutton
    menu.style.visibility = 'hidden'; //on masque le menu
  } else {

   const element = document.querySelector('#attributs_cadre')

   const Cadre_width = element.style.width
   if(Cadre_width != 310){ 
      element.style.width = '310px';
      document.querySelector("#tableauAttributs").style.width = '310px';
      document.querySelector("#tableauAttributs thead").style.width = '310px';
    }

    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
      ;
      tablinks[i].className = 'tablinks'; //on desactive tous les boutons
      tabcontent[i].style.visibility = 'hidden'; //on masque tous les menus
    };
    evt.currentTarget.className = "tablinks active"; //puis on active le bouton
    var style = style = window.getComputedStyle(menu);
    menu.style.visibility = 'visible'; //on affiche ce menu et actualise le css
    menu.style.position = style.getPropertyValue('position');
    menu.style.top = pos[1] + 'px';
    menu.style.left = (pos[0] + larg + 2) + 'px';
    menu.style.height = style.getPropertyValue('height');
    if (evt.currentTarget.id == 'Par') {
      menu.style.width = '320px'
    } else {
      menu.style.width = style.getPropertyValue('width');
    }
    menu.style.backgroundColor = style.getPropertyValue('backgroundColor');
    menu.style.color = style.getPropertyValue('color');
    menu.style.borderRadius = style.getPropertyValue('borderRadius');
    menu.style.boxShadow = style.getPropertyValue('boxShadow');
    menu.style.zIndex = style.getPropertyValue('zIndex');
  };
};

/**
 * gestion des boutons pour afficher le menu
 * @param evt: l'evenement du click
 *
 * @returns affiche le menu
 */
//pour activer les clics boutons menus
window.onload = function() {
  menu(evt);
  document.getElementById(this.id).onclick = menu;
}

document.getElementById("Par").onclick = menu;



function getPosition(Id) {
  console.trace('getPosition(Id)')
  var left = 0;
  var top = 0;
  //On récupère l'élément
  var e = document.getElementById(Id);
  console.log("e", e)
  //Tant que l'on a un élément parent
  while (e.offsetParent != undefined && e.offsetParent != null) {
    //On ajoute la position de l'élément parent
    left += e.offsetLeft + (e.clientLeft != null ? e.clientLeft : 0);
    top += e.offsetTop + (e.clientTop != null ? e.clientTop : 0);
    e = e.offsetParent;
  }
  return new Array(left, top);
};
```

And the CSS code

```
   /* Style the tab */

      #menu1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 70px;
        left: 5px;
        z-index: 1000;
      }

      .tab {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        width: 44px;
        height: 44px;
      }

      /* Style the buttons inside the tab */

      .tab button {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        background-color: rgba(235, 107, 10, 1);
        color: #4d2e00;
        padding: 8px 1px 8px 1px;
        width: 34px;
        border: 1px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        outline: none;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s;
        font-family: Rubik;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 900;
        font-style: normal;
        color: white;
      }

      /* Change background color of buttons on hover */

      .tab button:hover {
        background-color: rgba(196, 89, 8, 0.8);
        color: white;
      }

      /* Create an active/current "tab button" class */

      .tab button.active {
        background-color: rgba(122, 56, 5, 0.8);
        color: white;
      }

      /* pour enlever le focus du bouton */

      button::-moz-focus-inner {
        border: 0;
      }

      #ParContent {
        position: absolute;
        top: 70px;
        left: 42px;
        height: 390px;
        width: 220px;
        background-color: white;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 1px #999;
        visibility: hidden;
        z-index: 1000;
      }

      .titrePanneau {
        height: 20px;
        font-weight: 700;
        background-color: #6a360d;
        padding-left: 2px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .soustitrePanneau {
        font-weight: 700;
        background-color: gray;
        text-align: center;
      }


      /* panneau utilitaire parcellaire #ParContent*/


      #attributs_cadre {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        left: 2px;
        width: 310px;
        padding: 2px;
        height: 187px;
      }

      #type,
      #attributs {
        height: 20px;
        font-weight: 700;
        background-color: gray;
        text-align: center;
      }

      #ajoutAttrCav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 1px;
        right: 52px;

        height: 20px;
        width: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        text-decoration-line: none;
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 18px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      #ajoutLigne {
        position: absolute;
        top: 1px;
        right: 35px;

        height: 20px;
        width: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        text-decoration-line: none;
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      #ajoutAttrEmp {
        position: absolute;
        top: 2px;
        right: 15px;

        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        text-decoration-line: none;
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      #supprimLignes {
        position: absolute;
        top: 1px;
        right: 4px;

        height: 20px;
        width: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        text-decoration-line: none;
        font-family: arial;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      #tableauAttributs {
        position: absolute;
        width: 290px;
        top: 24px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-spacing: 0px;

        border-collapse: collapse;
      }

      #tableauAttributs tr .ent {
        border: 1px solid white;
        text-align: center;
      }

      #tableauAttributs tbody {
        display: block;
        max-height: 134px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }

      #tableauAttributs input {
        /*box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        */
      }

      #tableauAttributs tbody .td {
        width: 50%;
      }

      #tableauAttributs{ width:100%; }

      #tableauAttributs thead{
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
      }

      #tableauAttributs tbody tr{ 
        display: table;
        width: 103%;
        table-layout: fixed;
      }

      #tableauAttributs td {
        width: 90%;
      }

      #tableauAttributs thead {
        max-width:400px;
        max-height:22px;
        background: #b3b3b3;
      }
```

Comment: hello,
Ok thanks, it solved the tableauAttributs and the thead
but not the input cells

Comment: on each resize the input cell height is getting smaller and smaller

Comment: yes it's the css box-sizing that I remove.
now, it remains the middle of the columns that do not fit like the headers

Comment: I finally succeeded.
thank you for your tests.
http://jsfiddle.net/ericire/ayw1vfb5/16/